# Does buying stuff use up Special Task Medals in War Thunder?

Tags: war-thunder

In the War Bonds shop, some items require Special Task medals in addition to warbonds to purchase.

My question is this: does buying something that requires special task medals use them up like warbonds, or can they be reused?